# When installing Spotify I get an error

Tags: spotify

This is the error I get installing spotify:

```
 Errors were encountered while processing:
   /var/cache/apt/archives/spotify-client_1%3a1.0.28.89.gf959d4ce-37_amd64.deb
 E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: That is merely a summary of the installation process; the real error is given earlier. Please retry to install spotify and tell us what the earlier, actual error says.

Comment: How did you installed `Spotify`?

Comment: Please specify the procedure used to install spotify and paste the complete log. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

When installing packages that are external to aptitude (i.e. using `sudo dpkg -i packagename.deb`), dependency errors often occur.

In *most* cases, this can be fixed by running the following command immediately after the dpkg installation has failed:

```
sudo apt-get -f install
```

This command essentially tries to resolve any outstanding dependency issues.

It could also simply be that the package You are trying to install ins incompatible with Your Ubuntu version.